# How to inject css file in pixi.js

Tags: javascript, css, pixi.js

I'm new to `pixi.js`, I'm trying to use CSS with it.

For example: 
If I have a file name called blabla.css, inside of it I have a CSS code for a button. And I have a script.js and I'm coding my .js file using a pixi framework, how can I inject the css file into the pixi code.

note: I dont want to keep using the .style class to change the style inside the js.

Hope you understood my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pixi is a canvas framework. 
CSS can only manipulate DOM elements.

It's not possible to apply CSS styles to pixels that you display inside a canvas.

Comment: I understand, do you know whats the best way to css elements using pixi?